# how to fill areas based on cliques?

Tags: r, igraph

I have two cliques of 3 vertex of the graph

```
g9<- graph(c(0,1,0,2,0,3,1,4,1,2,3,4,3,5,4,5,5,2),n=6,dir=FALSE)
```

cliques are: `a[0 1 2],b[3 4 5]`

how to fill these cliques on plot(g9)???

I tried with

```
colorT<-gray.colors(2) 
polygon(c(x1a,x2a,x3a),c(y1a,y2a,y3a),col = colorT[1])
polygon(c(x1b,x2b,x3b),c(y1b,y2b,y3b),col = colorT[2])
```

The problem is that it doesn't coincide with the graph g9(Coordinates), Areas should be on plot of g9.

How can I do that?(Please it would be better if you show me a example about it)

Answer (score 4):

The `plot` function in igraph 0.6 (the development version, not the current stable one) has an argument called `mark.groups` which lets you specify groups of vertices that should be marked by filled polygons on the layout. E.g.:

```
plot(g9, mark.groups=list(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6)))
```

Note that this won't work in igraph 0.5.x; also note that I wrote `1,2,3` instead of `0,1,2` because igraph 0.6 uses 1-based vertex indices in the R interface, unlike igraph 0.5.x which uses 0-based indices.